# Best choice to store data in iOS Application

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an iOS application (iPad), my problem is to choose how to store my data (I have an equivalent of 1Mb of data).
What is the best one to choose and Why ? (Property list, XML, SQlite,.).

thanks for our answers.

Comment: Is that 1 month of data or 1 megabyte of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not enough information to answer your question properly. There are a lot of factors that affect the decision. Persistence libraries and frameworks all have very special constraints and learning curves.

Here are some questions to be taken into account:

1. What kind of data?
2. How much data?
3. How often does the data change and in which patterns?
4. Where does the data come from (server, user input)
5. Do you want to synchronize data (iCloud, Dropbox, other services)
6. What are typical access patterns? (Database vs. whole file)
7. Shall the data be portable?

Comment: Thanks for your answers : 1: Strings data. 2: 1Mo. 3:?? 4: user input. 5:Yes i want to synchronize 6:?? 7:??

Comment: Seems like a simple plist might be easiest.